# How to say "to move (house) from A to B" (change residence) in Japanese?

Tags: word-choice, words, nuances, usage, verbs

How to say "to move (house) from A to B" (change residence) in Japanese?

[Here](https://hinative.com/questions/1849869), it says the word is 引っ越す hikkosu, so I searched it on my dictionary and could not find how to use it in the complex pattern "from A to B".

Four precise questions:

(1) What is the correct verb for "to move (house)"/"to change residence"?

(2) How to use it in the complex pattern "move from A to B"?

(3) My dictionary uses the particle に and へ to express the direction in the simple pattern "move to B". Can I use まで in this simple pattern "move to B"? (Paul move to the U.S. --> Paulはアメリカまで引っ越した)

(4) Can I use 移動する?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As for 1, 引っ越す is the most common word in speech. A synonymous kango is 転居する. If you go far (e.g. to a foreign country) on a permanent basis, 移住する can be used as well. When you move from Tokyo to Osaka and back to Tokyo again, this can be described as

- 東京から大阪に引っ越してまた戻ってきた.

Here you cannot use 移住した. When you do 移住, usually you'll never return.

2 and 3: *to move from A to B* is usually AからBに(へ)引っ越す. Bまで引っ越す is not impossible, but much less common.

For 4, no. 移動する in a similar usage would mean *to travel*. E.g., 東京からＮＹに(へ、まで)移動した means *(I) travelled from Tokyo to NY.*

Comment: I guess Paulはイングランドからアメリカに引っ越した, even with a possible return to England, is possible, but a bit weird? In that case, is 転居する preferrable?

Comment: @starckman I think it fine except normally we say イギリス for England.

Comment: Thank you. Wikipedia has イングランド as a translation of "England" https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%82%A4%E3%83%B3%E3%82%B0%E3%83%A9%E3%83%B3%E3%83%89, and イギリス as a translation of "United Kingdom" https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%82%A4%E3%82%AE%E3%83%AA%E3%82%B9

Comment: @starckman Yeah, but a typical Japanese does not distinguish England and UK unless it is about football. (So England in World cup is referred to as イングランド代表, in most other cases イギリス is used.)